# Как заполнить QStringList c++?

Tags: c++, qt

Есть код допустим:

```
QStringList lst = {};
```

Как мне прибавить значение\заполнить массив этот?

```
lst.insert("Hello")

qDebug() << lst;
// И тут вывод: ["Hello"]
```

Такое возможно как то сделать?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#append

Comment: А вы пробовали?

Answer (score 1):

Использование метода append

```
QStringList list;
list.append("one");
list.append("two");
list.append("three");
```

Использование оператора <<

```
QStringList list;
list << "one";
list << "two";
list << "three";
```

Comment: или так. QStringList list = QStringList() << "one" << "two" << "three";